# Ajuda com manipulação após upload e move file em PHP

Tags: php

Após fazer upload do arquivo, e enviado as informações do formulário para página PHP, recebo o arquivo com `$_FILES['MyFile']`. Após receber o arquivo, eu faço a movimentação dele para outra pasta do meu sistema: 
`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['MyFile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['MyFile']['name'])){ ...`

O meu problema é. Após movimentar este arquivo para um novo diretório, eu não consigo fazer a leitura dele no diretório novo. Para exemplificar vou deixar uma parte do código aqui:

```
$fil = $_FILES['file-intimacao'];
$uploaddir = 'files/';
$files = '';

if(move_uploaded_file($fil['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($fil['name']))){
    $files = $uploaddir.$fil['name']; // novo diretório do arquivo
    $teste = file_exists ( $files ); //$teste me retorna falso, não me deixando utilizar o arquivo.
}
```

Comment: o diretorio tem permissões de leitura?

Comment: Você já conferiu se o diretório `files` está com permissão de leitura e escrita?

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas se for o que ta descrito em propriedades da pasta, esta "somente leitura". Mas não consigo tirar essa seleção de "somente leitura"

Comment: @Kazzkiq ? Miguel Borges ?

Comment: Como você está tentando mover um arquivo para esta pasta através do PHP, ela precisa ter a "escrita" habilitada também, caso contrário o sistema operacional vai barrar a ação do servidor. Para mudar esta opção você precisa ser administrador do computador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$fil = $_FILES;
$uploaddir = 'files/';
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$destino = $uploaddir.$fil['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($fil['tmp_name'], $destino)){            
    $teste = file_exists ( $destino ); 
}
```

Verifique também se a pasta files existe e tem permissão de gravação.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique as permissões do diretório. Se o ambiente for Linux, você pode usar o comando chmod() do PHP após a transferência:

Mais info: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chmod.php

Comment: ambiente é windows